# What is this "AssocGrpNodeLimit" mentioned when running the SLURM command "squeue"?

Tags: slurm

What is `AssocGrpNodeLimit`? The `squeue` command shows it listed as the "reason" my job is not running yet. I'm surprised, because some of the nodes are idle. My priority is the highest I've ever seen it (2126). I've Googled and Binged it, and I found it as a return value in [slurm_protocol_defs.c](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/src/common/slurm_protocol_defs.c):

```
/* Given a job's reason for waiting, return a descriptive string */
extern char *job_reason_string(enum job_state_reason inx)
{

...

case WAIT_ASSOC_GRP_NODE:
        return "AssocGrpNodeLimit";
```

Based on the words and word fragments comprising "AssocGrpNodeLimit", I'm guessing that someone associated with the same group as me is using too many nodes so my job won't run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AssocGrpNodeLimit is the limit of number of nodes set for the *association* of the submitted job.

You can check the limit with `sacctmgr show assoc` and if not limited by the administrators you can also list the jobs of the particular account with `squeue -A <account_name>`

---

Definition of the term *association* from http://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html (emphasis in the original):

> Slurm account information is recorded based upon four parameters that form what is referred to as an *association*. These parameters are
>   *user*, *cluster*, *partition*, and *account*. *user* is the login name. *cluster*
>   is the name of a Slurm managed cluster as specified by the *ClusterName*
>   parameter in the *slurm.conf* configuration file. *partition* is the name
>   of a Slurm partition on that cluster. *account* is the bank account for
>   a job.

Comment: Come to find out, the administrators were getting ready to restart the cluster so they prevented any new jobs from starting.

Comment: That is not the best way to prevent jobs starting. It would be more informative to set the partitions Down

Comment: Would that put nodes with running jobs into Drain mode?

Comment: No, but it would prevent any new job to start

Comment: Best way IMHO is to create a reservation for root with all nodes. That way, the nodes can still be used until the very last moment, with short jobs.